# Can't set a default nor initial nor first value to a pgfkey

Tags: pgfkeys

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\pgfkeys{/tikz/scale/.show code}

\pgfkeys{tikz/.cd,
    scale/.append code={\pgfgettransformentries\scale\ab\ba\bb\xhsift\yshift},
    %scale/.initial=1, %bad
    %scale/.default=1, %bad
    %scale = 1,  %bad
}

%\tikzset{/tikz/scale=1} % bad

\begin{document}
% doesn't work
%\begin{tikzpicture}
%   \node {*\scale*} ;
%\end{tikzpicture}

% work
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/scale = 2}
    \node {*\scale*} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You made scale a function, not a constant.

Comment: Scale stay scale but each call the code is executed and put some result in \scale. I want to initiate a first value before the first call.

Comment: `scale` is not a value key. You need to run it to do something like `\tikzset{scale=1}`

Comment: @percusse I tried several methods. See my code. If you have solution write an answer please.

Comment: Do you want access to the value that was last used with `scale`? Or do you just need the first element of the transformation matrix? In the first case, I'd just set the default via `\def\scale{1}`. In some special cases the transformation keys do not apply the transformations directly, so you might still get the wrong value.